# How to troubleshoot 502 Bad Gateway error

Tags: c#, rest-client

I have

```
curl --include --request POST --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --data-binary "username=xx@xxtemple.net&password=XXXXXXXX" 'https://api.xxsuccess.com/v1/auth'
```

running without **ANY errors** and go what I want.

When I run the following C# code on the **SAME machine**, I got 502 Bad Gateway Error:

```
string requestUri = "https://api.xxsuccess.com";
var client = new RestClient(requestUri);
client.Authenticator = new RestSharp.Authenticators.HttpBasicAuthenticator("xx@xxtemple.net", "XXXXX");
var request = new RestRequest("v1/auth", Method.POST);
IRestResponse restResponse = client.Execute(request);
```

Any idea how troubleshoot the problem ?
Why "Curl" is working and the code is not.

Comment: Are you sure this server accepts Basic Authentication? Your curl request looks different...

Answer (score 0):

`--data-binary` does POST the data (in this case your username and password) in the request body. HttpBasic Authentication puts your authentication info into the `Authorization` header. So these are different requests.

If the first request is working, you need to put the data in the body also for the RestSharp request

```
var client = new RestClient(requestUri);
var request = new RestRequest("v1/auth", Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("username","yourusername", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
request.AddParameter("password","yourpassword", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
```

Comment: Hi @derpirscher , when I  run ` var client = new RestClient(requestUri);
var request = new RestRequest("v1/auth", Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("username","yourusername", ParameterType.RequestBody); `  I have ` restResponse.Content = "{\"code\":\"InvalidContent\",\"message\":\"username/password are required\"}" `  Am I still missing anything ?
request.AddParameter("password","yourpassword", ParameterType.RequestBody);  IRestResponse restResponse = client.Execute(request); `

Comment: Again, **curl** is working without any problem with the same credentials on the same machine.

Comment: It might help if you could post a link to the api documentation

Comment: Hi @derpirscher ,  here is the link https://clientsuccessapi.docs.apiary.io/#reference/authentication/access-token/create-an-access-token

Comment: @BorisB Sorry, but seems I used the wrong paramtertype ... `RequestBody` vs `GetOrPost`. One should not only rely on the name of an enum value but also read the docs ... Please see the updated answer. With this request I now get `Unauthorized` as expected

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776927/derpirscher  , it works out!